# How do I get logs/details of ansible-playbook module executions?

Tags: logging, ansible

Say I execute the following.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
exit 0

$ cat Hello.yml
---

- hosts: MyTestHost
  tasks:
  - name: Hello yourself
    script: test.sh


$ ansible-playbook  Hello.yml

PLAY [MyTestHost] ****************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [MyTestHost]

TASK: [Hello yourself] ********************************************************
ok: [MyTestHost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
MyTestHost                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

$
```

I know for sure that it was successful.

**Where/how do I see the "Hello World" echo'ed/printed by my script on the remote host (MyTestHost)? Or the return/exit code of script?**

My research shows me it would be possible to write a plugin to intercept module execution callbacks or something on those lines and write a log file. I would prefer to not waste my time with that.

E.g. something like the stdout in below (note that I'm running ansible and not ansible-playbook):

```
$ ansible plabb54 -i /project/plab/svn/plab-maintenance/ansible/plab_hosts.txt -m script -a ./test.sh
plabb54 | success >> {
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "Hello World\n"
}

$
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If you pass the `-v` flag to ansible-playbook on the command line, you'll see the stdout and stderr for each task executed:

```
$ ansible-playbook -v playbook.yaml
```

Ansible also has built-in support for logging. Add the following lines to your [ansible configuration file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg):

```
[defaults] 
log_path=/path/to/logfile
```

Ansible will look in several places for the config file:

- `ansible.cfg` in the current directory where you ran `ansible-playbook`
- `~/.ansible.cfg`
- `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Comment: Thanks. Just greedy: Can I dynamically start/stop logging from a playbook? Like `set -x` and `set +x` in a shell script.

Comment: @thekashyap I don't think this is currently possible.

Comment: You can use the `no_log: True` flag to prevent a command or playbook from logging but that's as fine grained as it gets I believe.

Comment: Could you please describe how do I put `logrotate` to `log_path` so that every `ansible` run has a different file (with the command/playbook included in the file)?

Comment: I needed three `v`s to get stdout and stderr

Comment: You might need to go up to five `v`s depending on what you're doing.

Comment: This is good, but is there a way to have the stdout be normal output but the log file be debug output? I want to run playbooks and see the normal output scroll by in the terminal but debug data in the log file in case I need to investigate problems.

Answer (score 27):

There is also other way to generate log file.

Before running `ansible-playbook` run the following commands to enable logging:

- Specify the location for the log file.

  > export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=~/ansible.log
- Enable Debug

  > export ANSIBLE_DEBUG=True
- To check that generated log file.

  > less $ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH

Comment: ANSIBLE_DEBUG is kind of separate from specifying a log file. It's even separate from the verbosity selection! This is still very good to call out - debug will give you developer-oriented debug messages, on absolutely extreme verbosity level. Good to have around.

Answer (score 26):

The playbook script task will generate `stdout` just like the non-playbook command, it just needs to be saved to a variable using `register`. Once we've got that, the [debug module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) can print to the playbook output stream.

```
tasks:
- name: Hello yourself
  script: test.sh
  register: hello

- name: Debug hello
  debug: var=hello

- name: Debug hello.stdout as part of a string
  debug: "msg=The script's stdout was `{{ hello.stdout }}`."
```

Output should look something like this:

```
TASK: [Hello yourself] ******************************************************** 
changed: [MyTestHost]

TASK: [Debug hello] *********************************************************** 
ok: [MyTestHost] => {
    "hello": {
        "changed": true, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "test.sh", 
            "module_name": "script"
        }, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stdout": "Hello World\r\n", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Hello World"
        ]
    }
}

TASK: [Debug hello.stdout as part of a string] ******************************** 
ok: [MyTestHost] => {
    "msg": "The script's stdout was `Hello World\r\n`."
}
```

Comment: but Hello yourself task  have not given any stdout

Comment: This is my preferred method. Get good at using the values of registered variables in debug statements and the world is your oyster.

Answer (score 8):

**Offical plugins**

You can use the [output callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/callback.html). For example, starting in Ansible 2.4, you can use the [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/callback/debug.html) output callback plugin:

```
# In ansible.cfg:
[defaults]
stdout_callback = debug
```

(Altervatively, run `export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug` before running your playbook)

Important: you must run `ansible-playbook` with the `-v` (`--verbose`) option to see the effect. With `stdout_callback = debug` set, the output should now look something like this:

```
TASK [Say Hello] ********************************
changed: [192.168.1.2] => {
    "changed": true,
    "rc": 0
}

STDOUT:


Hello!



STDERR:

Shared connection to 192.168.1.2 closed.
```

There are other modules besides the `debug` module if you want the output to be formatted differently. There's `json`, `yaml`, `unixy`, `dense`, `minimal`, etc. ([full list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list)).

For example, with `stdout_callback = yaml`, the output will look something like this:

```
TASK [Say Hello] **********************************
changed: [192.168.1.2] => changed=true 
  rc: 0
  stderr: |-
    Shared connection to 192.168.1.2 closed.
  stderr_lines:
  - Shared connection to 192.168.1.2 closed.
  stdout: |2-

    Hello!
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

**Third-party plugins**

If none of the official plugins are satisfactory, you can try the `human_log` plugin. There are a few versions:

- https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log
- https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180

Answer (score 5):

Using callback plugins, you can have the stdout of your commands output in readable form with the play:
[gist: human_log.py](https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180)

> Edit for example output:

```
 _____________________________________
< TASK: common | install apt packages >
 -------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||


changed: [10.76.71.167] => (item=htop,vim-tiny,curl,git,unzip,update-motd,ssh-askpass,gcc,python-dev,libxml2,libxml2-dev,libxslt-dev,python-lxml,python-pip)

stdout:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.


stderr:

start:
2015-03-27 17:12:22.132237

end:
2015-03-27 17:12:22.136859
```

Answer (score 4):

Ansible command-line help, such as `ansible-playbook --help` shows how to increase output verbosity by setting the verbose mode (-v) to more verbosity (-vvv) or to connection debugging verbosity (-vvvv). This should give you some of the details you're after in stdout, which you can then be logged.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-v` or `--verbose` to see more debug messages.

Adding multiple `-v` will increase the verbosity, the builtin plugins currently evaluate up to `-vvvvvv`.
A reasonable level to start is `-vvv`, connection debugging might require `-vvvv`. (from the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-v))